# Vuejs - disable button until all input fields are completed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in my vue app:

This is the button of the form I need to disable

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="nextButton" @click.prevent="showNext(2)" :disabled="!disableButton">
  Next
</button>
```

And this is the logic I want to use

```js
    computed: {
        disableButton(){
            return !this.store.name || !this.store.surname || !this.store.email || !this.store.phone || this.store.invalidPhone || !this.store.pdv || !this.store.desiredDate || !this.store.desiredHour || !this.store.privacyFlag
        }
    }
```

I've created a simple stor to persist the data across the components, inside each component I'm importing the store file and inside the data function I'm also importing

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const store = reactive({...})
```

I need to disable the next button until the user insert all the required informations, I'm trying with a computed but without success, everytime the button will stay enabled or remain disabled also if I've inserted all the infromations. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Not sur, because you don't have a worked example where i can see the problem.
But you say name or surname or email .... You have to say i disable the button if i don't have name and surname .... So in first step you have to replace your ```||``` by ```&&```

Comment: @RaphaelRlt I've tried with the `&&` operator but when all the informations are inserted the button will stay disabled.

Comment: I post a answer because i can't write proper code ir

Answer (score 4):

Without working example is hard to be 100% sure, but as far as I see you have issue in logic.

You have:

```
:disabled="!disableButton"
```

and you should have

```
:disabled="disableButton"
```

Comment: As I've mentioned inside a comment, I've also tried to replace the `||` with `&&` but the button will remain disabled, or it will be enabled when the from is blank and no input is entered! Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Please, provide more details about this object you are passing to `store` variable through `reactive({...})`

Answer (score 2):

You could make the condition inside the computed shorter:

```js
 computed: {
        enableButton(){
            return Object.values(this.store).every(v=>!!v)
        }
    }
```

and `:disabled="!enableButton"`, this makes sense

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you'are checking for all the object entries to see if all values are set?I'm not sure if I can use this because I also have other data inside the object and not only the user infromation linke name, surname, phone ecc..

Answer (score 2):

To respond to your comment in more clear way.

You need to check the different value, but in this context i presume your value is filled with some string.
You just need to do something like this:

```
 computed: {
        fieldIsFilled(){
            return this.store.name && this.store.surname && this.store.email && this.store.phone && this.store.invalidPhone && this.store.pdv && this.store.desiredDate && this.store.desiredHour && this.store.privacyFlag
        }
    }
```

And attach this to the button like this:

> If the fields is filled the computed is true, so we reverse the result
> to disabled the button when the field is not filled.

```
<button :disabled="!fieldIsFilled">
  Next
</button>
```

For informatin i think you have some trouble and don't understand what you done because you have a error in your code, watch the line :

```
!this.store.name || !this.store.surname || !this.store.email || !this.store.phone || this.store.invalidPhone || !this.store.pdv || !this.store.desiredDate || !this.store.desiredHour || !this.store.privacyFlag
```

You have `this.store.invalidPhone` without the exclamation point, not sur but it's maybe not what you want too.

Comment: the `invalidPhone` will return false if the number is invalid and true if it's valid, this is why I didn't added the exclamation into the expression

Comment: So my function fieldIsFilled is accurate because, your field is valid if name exist ..... and if invalidPhone is true, you don't have to do the reverse.
If it's not work it's because you have a problem with your store.

Comment: not tested yet, but I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo that will check if any of the provided fields is empty then make the button disabled otherwise enable it. Try to empty any field and you should see that button will be disabled.

You can try matching your approach with this one.

```js
const App = {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      name: "name",
      surname: "surname",
      email: "email",
      phone: "phone",
      invalidPhone: "invalidPhone",
      pdv: "pdv",
      desiredDate: "desiredDate",
      desiredHour: "desiredHour",
      privacyFlag: "privacyFlag",
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shouldDiabled() {
      let emptyField = ["name", "surname", "email", "phone", "invalidPhone", "pdv", "desiredDate", "desiredHour", "privacyFlag"].find(prop => !this[prop])
      return emptyField;
    }
  }

};

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="name">
  <input v-model="surname">
  <input v-model="email">
  <input v-model="phone">
  <input v-model="invalidPhone">
  <input v-model="pdv">
  <input v-model="desiredDate">
  <input v-model="desiredHour">
  <input v-model="privacyFlag">
  <button @click.prevent="showNext(2)" :disabled="shouldDiabled">
  Next
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using a lazy v-model, will this work or the example will only work for normal v-model attribute?

Comment: For a lazy modifier, this example will only work when you lose focus from any input.